# FileZilla, Local files

Tags: ftp, filezilla

I've got kind of a dumb question but am stumped. I need to figure out how to setup the local path on FileZilla for my computer but am unsure of where to find this information, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this a FileZilla FTP Server you are talking about ?

Comment: What does it mean "setup the local path"? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

I believe one way to do it is to configure a site bookmark. It will save both the remote directory (FTP server name and path on that server) and the local directory.

[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/422205/whats-the-best-way-to-use-filezillas-bookmarks-site-manager) discusses how to use site bookmarks in detail.